# my ubuntu system getting stuck while starting elastic search service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have a ubuntu 18.04 system with 4 gb ram and 500gb hard disk.I have installed elastic search  in my system  like "sudo apt-get install elasticsearch"

but while starting elastic search with command : sudo service elasticsearch start

My system getting stuck, I am unable to do any thing.  how to fix this

Comment: Maybe the best place for such question is in "Ask Ubuntu"?

Comment: brew info elasticsearch@version

Keep the logs running before starting elastic search and then check the logs...

Comment: check free ram on os and check jvm.options for xmx and xms. maybe you don't have enough memory

Answer (score 2):

**CPU and (RAM)memory used by Elasticsearch is very high. So you can tell the elastic search that you can only use a specific amount of memory.**

1. First go to */etc/elasticsearch/*
2. Just see the directory structure and you will get a file named *jvm.options*
3. Just allocate the memory by adding 2 lines of code in jvm.options file:
   `-Xms1g -Xmx1g`
4. Just restart your elasticsearch and enjoy it :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can answer this question as I have encountered this problem a while ago and have also resolved it after some R&D.My ROR application is Live and have more than 8000+ images and CPU Intensive as there is lot more happening in my server as every request uses LAT/LNG to serve a geo-calculated response.I was facing this low memory issue similarly like yours when i started and reindexed my data on elasticsearch.

**My Learnings-**

1. ElasticSearch is a monster that will eat up your ram.
2. No Matter how optimized your keywords are OR the data is, that you are pushing to the elasticSearch to get indexed, you must keep a default buffer of backup memory.

**What I did...that resolved my issue...**

1. [Add a Swap space](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) which acts like a backup memory in case your RAM is eaten up.
2. I also upgraded to 8GB HD to be on safer side.

Now since i have followed the above mentioned steps, i am not facing any low memory error despite the size of my  indexex data becoming huge every month.Furthermore I am still good to go error free and memory related issues while indexing this huge data.

**One more thing, which I recently did to improve memory consumption** of my Rails app is injecting jmalloc inside my ruby 2.4.1.You can read more [here](https://medium.com/rubyinside/how-we-halved-our-memory-consumption-in-rails-with-jemalloc-86afa4e54aa3) but in simple words, It helps improve memory consumption of ruby apps.A copied explanation of Jmalloc would be like -

*Ruby traditionally uses the C language function malloc to dynamically allocate, release, and re-allocate memory when storing objects. Jemalloc is a malloc(3) implementation developed by Jason Evans (hence the “je” initials at the start of malloc), which appears to be more effective at allocating memory compared to other allocators due to its focus on fragmentation avoidance and scalable concurrency support.*

Below are my steps that I took to add Jmalloc into my existing Ruby 2.4.1 by reinstalling 2.4.1 on my Production server(after testing on staging/dev) using rvm.

```
 ===========CHECK RVM  --
 rvm info
 ============ check ruby version
 ruby -v
 ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
 ========== if ruby is installed, reinstall with Jemalloc and compile
 =============REINSTALL RUBY WITH JAMALLOC
 rvm reinstall 2.4.1 -C --with-jemalloc --disable-binary
 ============VERIFY JMALLOC IN THE BELOW LIST of ruby compiling list
 ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS']"
 -lpthread -ljemalloc -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

The Results of jmalloc being injected in ruby were just outstanding even after testing with 2000 random requests, my overall App memory was only 364MB and remained the same throughout by testing with below mentioned testing gems.

```
gem "memory_profiler"
gem "derailed_benchmarks"
```

hope it helps